# How to force server to bypass cache for HTTP POST?

Tags: http, post

Can a client force the origin server to ignore its cache when generating the response? For example, can it send `Cache-Control: no-cache` in a request? The RFC only seems to discuss `Cache-Control: no-cache` in the context of a response, not a request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question...

According to http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.1.6:

`A client's request MAY specify the maximum age it is willing to accept of an unvalidated response; specifying a value of zero forces the cache(s) to revalidate all responses.`

According to http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.4

`The request includes a "no-cache" cache-control directive [...] The server MUST NOT use a cached copy when responding to such a request.`